# Complex function on circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I have $f(z)= -\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ which, I believe, will map a circle into another circle. So if I start with a circle in the complex plane with centre $(x,y)$ of radius $r$ how do I determine the centre and radius after applying $f(z)$?

I can see that I substitute $x + iy$ for $z$ in the function $f(z)$ but then I have just an expression rather than an equation - don't I? (My university level maths is over $40$ years ago...). 
Thanks.

Comment: Under the assumption that any given circle is mapped onto another circle under this transformation, here is what you can do: Pick three points on the given circle. Find their images using $f(z)$. Now you have three points of the new circle. That information is enough to find the equation of the new circle, it's just algebra

Answer (score 1):

Moebius transformations map lines and circles into lines and circles, see

[A Möbius transformation maps circles and lines to circles and lines. What exactly does that mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460548/a-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-maps-circles-and-lines-to-circles-and-lines-what-exactl)

Remark for a reference: Your map is (the negative of) the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) 
$$
z\mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i},
$$
which
maps the upper half plane biholomorphically to the open unit disk.  So $f(z)$ maps $\infty$ to $-1$, $1$ to $i$ and $-1$ to $-i$.

Answer (score -1):

If I apply f to the center I get the new center, 
f(x, y) -> c'

If I apply f to a point on the circle I get a point on the new circle. e.g.

f(x - r, y) -> p

and so, from c' and p, can determine  the radius.

Isn't this correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct!